# How to setup workspace with gradle

Tags: gradle, setup-project

I want to create a labymod addon and i am currently trying to set it up. I need to enter "./gradlew setupDecompWorkspace" in the cmd to create the workspace. But when I enter the command, I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.9/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
```

When I use --stacktrace to get the error message, I receive the following message:

```
at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonGreeter.parseDaemonOutput(DaemonGreeter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startProcess(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:160)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonStarter.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonStarter.java:136)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.doStartDaemon(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:212)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.startDaemon(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.connect(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:130)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:139)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:93)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:52)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:207)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:402)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:375)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:23)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:368)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:298)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:108)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)